# Am I legally bound to transfer apartments if I don't like the new lease?

Tags: residential-lease

I am in the state of Texas and I inquired my apartment complex about transferring to a downstairs apartment.

The night before the transfer I get this new lease that is $30 more a month, plus a prorate that will have me paying close to $200 more for this month alone, plus a $250 deposit which I actually paid $500 deposit when I first moved in.

None of this was discussed beforehand, I asked if I could transfer, they said sure, I said that's it, nothing else? They said nope, you are all set.

So clearly this is a non-starter, the move is supposed to happen tomorrow, is there anything legal they can use against me if I just say, no thanks I will stay where I am?

By the way I have not signed anything and my current lease does not expire until November of this year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot be compelled to accept a modified lease that you never agreed to, and that was not even shown to you when you discussed the issue. You should notify the management in writing at once that you reject this "offer" and do not plan to transfer under those terms.